# /usr/bin/passwd and the CAP_CHOWN capability

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwd, linux-capabilities

I was experimenting with Linux Capabilities, and I noticed that for the `passwd` program to work without being Set-UID root, it needs to have the **CAP_CHOWN** capability (in addition to some others). Logically, why would it need to have **CAP_CHOWN** at all?

Incidentally, passwd gives me a "token manipulation error" if I remove the capability.

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 without SELinux. I'm trying to get `passwd` to work without being Set-UID root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cap_chown` is not required for the `passwd` itself. It is only needed to change the /etc/shadow file associated with the `userID`.
The /etc/shadow file is set so that it cannot be read by just anyone.

/etc/shadow is only accessible to root. So when /etc/passwd finishes it's authentication module and is ready to write a new (encoded) password, it will create a token. Which is accessed by the Linux-PAM service, which will chown it to root and write it into /etc/shadow.

## Edit:

passwd uses the files /etc/.pwd.lock, /etc/shadow , /etc/nshadow.
Since passwd reads and writes from /etc directory, w permissions are requried by it. Note that, /etc/shadow is never written by passwd. passwd actually writes to /etc/nshadow and renames /etc/nshadow to /etc/shadow.

```
open('/etc/nshadow',O_WRONLY|O_CREAT)=fd1
open('/etc/shadow', O_RDONLY)=fd2
fchown(fd1, uid=root, gid=shadow)
chmod /etc/shadow to : rw by owner and r by group
read(fd2)
write(fd1)
rename("/etc/nshadow", "/etc/shadow")
```

Furthermore, I confirmed the existence of `/etc/nshadow` using this C program. FYI,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
while(1)
if (access("/etc/nshadow",F_OK)!=-1){
    printf("Exists\n");
    break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify some of the things that you've written? I don't understand what you've written after _/etc/shadow is only accessible to root_

Answer (score 0):

`setuid` is all that originally was needed.

The additions of [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux) (*Security Enhanced*) requires the program context to be correct as well as file permission checks.

If the system's SE feature is disabled, `passwd` will work fine without any `CAP_...`.  Somewhere I read that SE can be disabled by writing a "1" to `/selinux/disable`.  Presumably writing "0" reenables it.

See [NSA's description](http://www.nsa.gov/research/selinux/index.shtml) or [Fedora's](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Managing_Confined_Services/).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. It doesn't have SELinux. Also, the objective here being that I wan't to remove the `setuid` bit and just have capabilities applied to passwd. (Reducing the over-privileged-binary problem)